# XCode, iPhone Project an SVN

Tags: iphone, xcode, svn

while coding a little iPhone App with a friend, we decided to use Subversion to share the code. While doing that, we found some small annoyances but I#m sure they are a result of our lack of experience with iPhone Projects and SVN.
While this is only a fun and learning Project, both of us have there own provisioning profile and if I check my Code changes in the Project File (.pbxuser )is for my user and vice versa. How do we work correctly with svn so that either of us can use their provisioning Profile?

Thank you

twickl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't check in *.pbxuser or build (I add them to svn:ignore).

Set the provisioning profile selection to one of the "automatic" options.